# how can we use prepare statement in jdbc since it is an interface

Tags: java, interface, jdbc

In JDBC except `DriverManager` all are interfaces. How are we able to use the interfaces such as, `PrepareStatement`, `Connection` etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drivermanager returns a concrete implementation of the `Connection`. The concrete implementation of the `Connection` in turn returns a concrete implementation of the `Statement`. The concrete implementation of the `Statement` in turn returns a concrete implementation of the `ResultSet`. And so on.

Those concrete implementations are provided by the JDBC driver. To learn about the underlying implementation, do a

```
System.out.println(connection.getClass());
```

You'll see that it's not `java.sql.Connection`, but just the one provided by the JDBC driver used.

Interfaces are just there to define a contract the implementor has to adhere. This enables you to reuse the same JDBC code with different JDBC drivers without the need to rewrite the code (expect of maybe DB specific SQL queries, but that's not a Java/JDBC problem) whenever you'd like to reuse the same code on a different DB server.

Answer (score 0):

The DriverManager (or [DataSource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html)) is your starting point -- get the Connection etc. from it. You don't need to directly instantiate any of these.

Answer (score 0):

**DriverManager :**

1. download the JDBC driver
2. put it in your JAVA projet
3. define path to the jar Driver in projet properties

**Example of Connection :**

```
public static void exampleOfConnection() {  
    try {
        /* How to instanciate a connection with a specific driver manager */
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection connectionDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:~/workspace/POEC/Data/films.sqlite");
        connectionDB.setAutoCommit(false);

        /* Begin of statements */
        /* Here are use statements */
        /* End of statements*/

        connectionDB.commit();
        connectionDB.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Example of Statement :**

```
public static void exampleOfStatementTest(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    String createFilmsTableQuery = "CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS films" + "("
            + " filmId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE ," + " filmTitle TEXT,"
            + " filmDirector TEXT," + " filmType TEXT," + " filmYear INTEGER " + ");";
    try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
        statement.execute(createFilmsTableQuery);
        statement.close();
    }
}
```

**Example of PrepareStatement** :

```
private static void exampleOfPrepareStatementTest(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    String insertIntoFilmsPrepareStatementQuery = "INSERT INTO films "
            + "(filmTitle, filmDirector, filmType, filmyear) " + "VALUES (? ,? ,? ,? )";
    try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertIntoFilmsPrepareStatementQuery);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "Jackie Brown");
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "Tarentino");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "detective film");
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, 1997);
        int filmAddedQuantity = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(filmAddedQuantity + " Film(s) added");
        preparedStatement.close();
        st.close();
    }
}
```